# 2 [main] hw3 10368 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to hw3.exe.stackdump

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, exception, cygwin

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int level = -1;
    int value = -5;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};

int array[100][100];
void storetree(node *root, int val);
void printtree();

int main()
{
    cout << " u there?" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = -5;
        }
    }

    ifstream file1;
    ifstream file2;
    file1.open("tree1.txt");
    file2.open("graph1.txt");
    node root;
    node *root1;
    int val1;
    int randval;

    file1 >> val1;
    root.level = 0;
    root1->level = 0;
    root.value = val1;
    root1->value = val1;
    array[0][0] = val1;

    cout << "made it" << endl;

    root1->left->value = -5;     // <-- Error happens here
    root1->right->value = -5;
    root1->left->level = -5;
    root1->right->level = -5;
```

So my error happens when I access root1->left->value, and I get the stack dump error.

Is it impossible to access root1->left->value the way I've written it? Through print statements I've deduced that this is the error. I don't understand pointers well and would appreciate help. :)

Comment: `root1->level=0` Here, `root1` is an uninitialized pointer, pointing to some random address in memory. By accessing it, your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I've annotated your source code below:

```
...

// Allocate an actual instance of your 'node' struct (local variable, on the stack)
node root;

// This allocates a POINTER variable, which just contains an address.
// The compiler knows that 'root1' will point at 'node' types.
// Note that you've only created a pointer variable here; NOT an actual node.
// Further, you haven't initialized it, so its value is "undefined"
// (you can't assume you know what its value is ... it could be anything).
node *root1;

...

// Set 'level' on the root node to zero
root.level = 0;    // This is OK, because root is an actual 'node' struct instance

// Set 'level' ON THE NODE THAT 'root1' POINTS TO to zero
root1->level = 0;  // This is not OK, because root1 is a wild (uninitialized) pointer
```

This is your first problem. You created a pointer, but you didn't point it at anything.
The value of `root1` (i.e., the address it refers to) is *undefined*
(could be NULL, could be whatever was in memory where that variable resides)

It's good practice to initialize your local variables *right when you define them*. Uninitialized variables can have undefined values, and that can add countless hours of debugging to your life, where each run of your program does something different from the last one. Bleh.

If you're not ready to assign the actual value when you define a variable,
set it to some *known* value like 0, `nullptr`, whatever. If you forget to set it later, your program will at least do the SAME wrong thing each time.

```
node *root1 = nullptr;  // (...or maybe your compiler uses "NULL" or "(void *)0"...)
```

It looks like you're going to be building up a tree of nodes based upon whatever you read in from the input file?
If so, then you're almost certainly going to be *dynamically* allocating node structs, since you can't know how many you'll need ahead of time.

```
// Allocate and initialize a new node struct (on the heap)
root1 = new node();

// Set 'level' ON THE NODE THAT 'root1' POINTS TO to zero
root1->level = 0;  // Yay, now this works
```

The variable `root1` now contains the address of the newly-allocated `node` struct. The rest of your code should work from there.

Just a reminder that a 'correct' program (e.g., one that doesn't leak memory) should ultimately call `delete` on every pointer returned by a call to `new`.
Also, keep that in mind as you're building your tree of dynamically-allocated `node` objects; you'll need to call `delete` on each of them (except for root, which you didn't allocate dynamically) when you're all done.

Comment: yea im dumb as hell ty ty

Comment: Do not be so impolite, not even towards your self. @ImaGoon

Comment: @ImaGoon - Don't sweat it. Most people have difficulty with pointers at first. If I made it sound obvious, it was only because I've been working with C/C++ for 30+ years.  :-)